# What does the notation $\left\{N_i\right\}$ stand for?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Just tried to read this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/9805024.pdf

On page two it says

> For instance, ten tosses of a die $(n = 6, N = 10)$ might have the outcome “1326642335.” Each outcome yields a set of sample numbers $\left\{N_i\right\}$ and relative frequencies $\left\{f_i = N_i/N, i = 1, \dots ,  n\right\}$.

My question is, **what exactly is meant by $\left\{N_i\right\}$?** I've seen this notation several times, but I don't really understand the definition of it. I tried to look it up, but googling math notation is quite difficult, and I did not succeed.

My try: Taking the above mentioned example outcome “1326642335”, I think that $\left\{N_i\right\} = \left\{ 1,2,3,1,1,2  \right\}$, since those numbers count the number of the occurrences of 1,2,3,...6. But then $\left\{N_i\right\} = \left\{ 1,2,3,1,1,2  \right\} = \left\{ 1,2,3  \right\} = \left\{ 3,1,2  \right\}$ since sets don't have a order and duplicates will be removed. This does not seem to make sense..

I'd be glad at any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, $\{N_i\}$ is shorthand for $\{N_i\}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}$ where $\mathcal{I}$ is an arbitrary index set. For instance, a sequence in the naturals, $N_1,N_2,\dots,N_n,\dots$ can be writen as $\{N_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, with shorthand notation $\{N_i\}$. In general $\{N_i\}$ is a collection or set of objects, for instance numbers, events, random variables, and so on.

**Edit:** Note that $\{N_i\}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}=\{N_i:i\in\mathcal{I}\}$

In the example you have, $N_i$ is a random variable that registers the number of trials showing the face with the "i" value, so indeed, the set that you have is a set of events, as follows $\{N_i\}=\{\{N_1=1\},\{N_2=2\}, \{N_3=3\}, \{N_4=1\}, \{N_5=1\}, \{N_6=2\}\}$, where the notation $N_i=\{1,2,3,1,1,2\}$ is a slight abuse of notation where implicit is the fact that each of the entries correspond to the outcome of each of the random variables and thus are not just "the same number".

Comment: Thanks! Great answer, but what is $\{N_i\}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}$ called? Does it have a name?

Comment: And, how does it differ from $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$? Are () and {} just the same?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if there is a specific name for the notation, but if you ask me, I associate it the most with sets/sequence notation, in cases where $N_i$ is understood from the context. I add an edit to elaborate more on the notation.

Comment: Tanks, sorry, but I haven't got enough reputation to upvote your answer.

Comment: @MichaelS when referring to sequences $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. However, in other contexts, one should be more careful. For instance, if dealing with matrices or vectors, sometimes the notation $(a_i)$ could denote the vector $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, and the notation $(a_{ij})$ could denote the matrix whose $ij$'th entry is $a_{ij}$. I don't think there's a gold standard for this things, and most books have golssary descriptions on what does each type of notation means throughout the reading.

Comment: @MichaelS that's fine, don't worry. I think you can click the checkmark on the answer to accept it as a valid answer. If not, the important part is for you to learn :)